# Nestjs / Typeorm rollback database state using transaction after each test

Tags: nestjs, typeform

I am trying to use Nestjs/Typeorm with transactions to start and rollback database state before/after each e2e test.

I have included a code snippet attempt below. I am trying to override the EntityManager provider so that it is initialised with a QueryRunner instance so that I can start and rollback a transaction before/after each test. However, I cannot seem to get the repository (see comments in beforeEach method in code snippet below) to use my overridden EntityManager instance, to enable successful transaction usage.....I think this is why the transaction is not rolling back after each test has completed??

```js
  let app: INestApplication;
  let testModule: TestingModule;

  afterEach(async () => {
    const em: EntityManager = testModule.get(getEntityManagerToken('default'));
    await em.queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const con: Connection = testModule.get(Connection);
    const em: EntityManager = testModule.get(getEntityManagerToken('default'));
    const repo: CourseRepository = testModule.get(CourseRepository);
    const result: boolean = repo.isEntityManagerMine(em); // false => the repo is not using the default entity manager
    const conResult: boolean = repo.isConnectionMine(em.connection); // true => the repo is using the same connection
    await em.queryRunner.startTransaction();
  });

  afterAll(async() => {
    await app.close();
    await testModule.close();
  });

  beforeAll(async () => {
    testModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],})
    .overrideProvider(getEntityManagerToken('default'))
    .useFactory({
      factory: (connection: Connection): EntityManager => {
        const queryRunner: QueryRunner = connection.createQueryRunner('master');
        const entityManager: EntityManager = connection.createEntityManager(queryRunner);
        return entityManager;
      },
      inject:[getConnectionToken('default')],
    })
    .compile();

    app = testModule.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

 // tests using request from supertest library
```

Comment: But you definitely want the state before the test ran, so wiping the database is not an option?!

Comment: Might have to go down that route.... Although would prefer rolling back the transaction for performance, puzzling why repository is not using EntityManager instance from provider....

Comment: I use `await getConnection().synchronize(true);` for dropping the database which is fast enough for my purposes. Maybe try it out and if you don't have a noticeable performance loss it's good enough

Comment: Thanks @KimKern, might have to give it a try...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue :
I am using **Nestjs + TypeORM + Jest** setup. I am using **DataMapper pattern**.

I figured, when we are writing **Integration Tests**, we are actually inserting record in the database. I also did not want to use new db where I had to create the schema and seed all the data - which could lead to increased time when my project become bigger. Another threat to using a separate db for testing is , making sure of the sequence in which you apply the changes. one wrong step and it could eat countless hours of my time in fixing the seed data .

The problem with inserting data in DB while running integration tests is -  for every insert done by the repository.insert() or repository.save() - typeorm creates a new transaction and commits it. This creates an issue if I **[ start a txn in beforeAll() - run the tests - rollback txn in afterAll() ]**, because there are already commits done at repository level. This renders above flow useless.

Following is the solution I followed.

- use same DB as dev env to do the Integration testing
- write your integration tests
- Write delete statements in afterAll() block

Following is the code block :

```
afterAll(async () => {
await queryRunner.startTransaction();
await queryRunner.query(`delete from \"Accounts\" 
    where \"walletWalletId\" in 
        (select \"wallet_id\" from \"Wallet\" 
            where \"userUuid\" = \'`+VALID_UUID+'\')');

await queryRunner.query(`delete from \"Wallet\"
    where \"userUuid\" = \'`+ VALID_UUID+'\'');

await queryRunner.query(`delete from \"Users\" 
    where \"uuid\" = \'`+VALID_UUID+'\'');
await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
});
```